# How can I reduce the number of PlotMarkers when I have many points in a ListLinePlot using the PlotTheme “Monochrome”?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

For example `ListLinePlot[Range[10000], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]` will show a marker for every point, how can I show  a marker just every hundred points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of Version 12.1 do not use `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`** (see update below)

---

Taking a sample of the points and then working with `Overlay` or `Show` (e.g. mixing `ListLinePlot`, `ListPlot`) is a rather cumbersome solution. (*Note, that just taking a sample of points, as the quickly accepted answer attempts, will not mark every hundredth point - it simply marks all points in a selection.*)

**There is a better way to achieve what the OP calls for (e.g. marking a selection of all points) by using [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html)**:

```
SeedRandom["08.01.2019"];
points = RandomVariate[ UniformDistribution[], 50 ];
ListLinePlot[
    points,
    Mesh -> 30, (* setting this to 50-2 = 48 will give all points *)
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"
]
```

[image: ListLinePlot]

Playing around with the number of points used for `Mesh` gives the idea:

[image]

So for completeness' sake using `Mesh` the solution to the OP's problem is approximately:

```
ListLinePlot[Range[10000], Mesh -> (10000/100), PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

**UPDATE**:

It seems that some things are broken in Version 12.1 as my solution will not work out (@XinBae points out, that earlier Versions had similiar issues).

I found the *culprit*: It is `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` which seems to break `Mesh`.

Compare the following output:

```
SeedRandom["08.01.2019"];
points = Sort@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 50];
GraphicsRow@{
  ListLinePlot[points, Mesh -> 2, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"],
  ListLinePlot[points, Mesh -> 2, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
}
```

[image: Mesh Problems]

Comment: @xin pei Note, that the topology of the plot is not affected. You called for less "Markers" not less "Points"!

Comment: Yes... Your answer is better

Comment: So why is this answer downvoted? Someone angry because of COVID-19? ;-)

Comment: Maybe not the COVID-19. This method  fails in version 12.1... In fact, in some previous versions, the mesh option also failed @gwr

Comment: @XinBae I see. The culprit is `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` see my update.

Comment: This works for single curves, and when you have to draw legends or more than one curve, more bugs will be found. So the solution is still to use a lower version of mathematica (for example 11.0 ). @gwr

Comment: @XinBae I do not believe using lower versions is a solution for anything - missing out on features and bug fixes for lots of other areas given the wider scope of programmes today - we re not simply plotting most of the time, are we?

Comment: I agree with you. but at present, there are many problems in this version of Plotting (12.1), for example, you copy and paste the pictures you painted above into word. When you open it again, the picture will become garbled.So I suggest not to use MM12.1 when drawing.@gwr

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
ListLinePlot[Range[10000][[1;;-1;;100]], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

The `[[1;;-1;;100]]` part specification picks one element every 100 elements.

Comment: Yes, it is. This will work for any list.

Comment: OP wants less marks but not less points.

Comment: @gwr You can always make two plots and combine them with `Show` - one `ListLinePlot` without markers, and one `ListPlot` employing this solution to get a marker every 100 points

Comment: @gwr What I meant is that you make the `ListLinePlot` with all data points, and only the `ListPlot` with the subset. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @LukasLang I am saying, that your suggestion will work but I am addressing this answer and it will not work in general. That is all.

Comment: Yes...It works though some details lost. just like resampling

Comment: @xinpei You should maybe be more precise in what you want? You explicitly called for less "markers" not less "points" in your post. This answer is not a valid answer for your problem as you posted it!