# Why do some PlotThemes not work with Mesh as expected? What can be done about it?

Tags: plotting, mesh, plot-themes

While updating my answer for [(189038)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189038/764) I noted that some `PlotThemes` do not work with `Mesh` in a meaningful way:

```
SeedRandom["08.01.2019"];
$plotThemes = Map[ToString] @ { Web, Monochrome, Detailed, Scientific, Business, Marketing, Classic, Minimal };
points = Sort@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 50];
ListAnimate @ Map[
    ListLinePlot[ points, 
       Mesh -> 2, 
       PlotLabel -> #, 
       PlotTheme -> #, 
       ImageSize -> Medium] &,
       $plotThemes
  ]
```

[image: PlotThemes]

There should only be two mesh points shown on the line, but this is not working properly for the following `PlotThemes`:

- **Monochrome**
- **Business**
- **Marketing**

**What can be done about this?**

Comment: Not really sure, why this question is downvoted—my answer for the linked question has been as well—maybe someone is out to get me? ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the option `PlotMarkers -> None`:

```
themes = "Base" /. Charting`$PlotThemes;

Grid @ Partition[ListLinePlot[points, Mesh -> 2,
 PlotMarkers->None, PlotLabel -> #, PlotTheme ->#, ImageSize -> Medium]& /@ themes, 2]
```

[image]

We need to add this option for the three themes (`"Business"`, `"Marketing"` and `"Monochrome"`) because other themes do not use the option `PlotMarkers`:

```
Grid[{#, Options[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, ListLinePlot], PlotMarkers] /. 
  HoldPattern[PlotMarkers -> x_List]:> Rule[PlotMarkers,{"..."}]}& /@ themes, 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]